# Git change parent commit rev

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

A colleague of mine checked out commit `correct_parent`, made some changes based on `correct_parent`, and then somehow mistakenly committed with another wrong parent commit rev `wrong_parent` instead of `correct_parent` (I'm not exactly sure how he managed to do that). Let's call his commit `bad_commit`.

A whole bunch of new commits are based on `bad_commit`, including new merge commits, so it's not simply a linear structure, but more like diamonds. They are all finally back being merged together into a single branch again. Let's call this `bad_branch`.

I want to recreate `bad_commit` with the correct parent commit `correct_parent`, and all follow-up commits as well.

I'm not exactly sure how to do that. Probably somehow with `git rebase` and `--strategy ours` or so. Note that this is not simply a rebase because the diff between `wrong_parent` and `bad_commit` are not sense-full, so I don't want to apply this as a patch.

A picture:

```
wrong_parent -> bad_commit (based on correct_parent) -> ...... -> bad_branch HEAD
```

I want:

```
correct_parent -> bad_commit (merge strategy: take bad_commit) -> .... -> fixed_branch
```

Comment: So some of commits based on `bad_commit` are actually merge commits? Maybe `git checkout -b correct_head_branch_tmp correct_parent && git rebase --preserve-merges correct_head_branch_tmp` will help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed with a graft file, made permanent using `git filter-branch`.

To set up a bad repo:

```
git init
echo a > file && git add file && git commit -m "good parent"
echo b > file && git add file && git commit -m "bad parent"
echo c > file && git add file && git commit -m "child" file
```

And this appears in `git log --oneline` simply as

```
f6e3133 child
4dc60b6 bad parent
7b5da8a good parent
```

Now to pretend "good parent" is the parent of "child":

```
echo `git rev-parse @ @~2` > .git/info/grafts
```

And check `git log --oneline` again:

```
f6e3133 child
7b5da8a good parent
```

Now to make it permanent:

```
git filter-branch
```

And check `git log --oneline` a third time:

```
87b8fc8 child
7b5da8a good parent
```

You see that the child got a new hash. That's because the commit was re-written with the proper parent. The parent didn't get a new hash, because it was unchanged. Any children of "child" would have been rewritten as well.

Finally, just clean up:

```
rm .git/info/grafts
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch from `correct_parent`,
and cherry pick the commits that happened on the other branch based on `wrong_parent`:

```
git checkout -b fix correct_parent
git cherry-pick wrong_parent..other_branch
```

*Thanks [@poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) for the suggestion!*

Comment: `git cherry-pick` also accepts a commit range, so you don’t need to use bash there. You can just use `first_commit..last_commit` to cherry-pick them all.

Comment: I thought that `cherry-pick` would try to apply them as patches - not just take exactly that state. I want the latter.

Comment: `cherry-pick` replays the changes in the specified commits, one by one, creating new commits, using the same messages as in the original commits. That doesn't suit you?

Comment: No, I don't want to apply the changes. I want to take the commit just as-is. Like the merging strategy "theirs".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like job for `git rebase`.

1. Create branch to point correct parent

`git checkout -b ok_branch <correct_parent>`

2. Do a rebase saving merges (reference http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

> -p
>   --preserve-merges
>
> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.
>
> This uses the --interactive machinery internally, but combining it with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

`git checkout -b replaced_branch <bad_branch>`

`git rebase --preserve-merges ok_branch`

3. drop temporary branch

`git branch -D ok_branch`

After these changes you'll have

`- correct parent [ok_branch] - bad commit - .... - HEAD [replaced_branch]`

**update**

You may find usesul flag `--onto` (reference https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#More-Interesting-Rebases)